# RNFirebase Messaging: Issue Sending Device Token in Time

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I am having a problem uploading the device token in time. It seems like the problem is because if permissions are not granted quickly enough, nothing gets updated to my database. But when I restart the app (after permissions have been granted), the device token is uploaded to my database as expected.

This is the code I am using, it is running when `componentWillMount()`.

```
FCM = firebase.messaging(); 
DB = firebase.database().ref('deviceTokens/'); 

  getPushToken() {
    FCM.requestPermissions();
    FCM.getToken().then(token => {
      DB.push(token);
     });

  }
```

Is there anyway I resolve this? I do not want the user to have to restart the app, after granting permissions, in order for me to get the device token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`requestPermissions` method returns promise so you need to wait until the function complete it work or fails , there are 2 ways to solve your problem

### #1 : using await

```
try{
    await FCM.requestPermissions();
    FCM.getToken().then(token => {
        DB.push(token);
    });
}catch(e){/*DO SOMETHING*/}
```

### #2 : using then method

```
FCM.requestPermissions().then(() => {
    FCM.getToken().then(token => {
        DB.push(token);
     });
}).catch(e => {/*DO SOMETHING*/} );
```

Answer (score 4):

Granting permissions requires an interaction with the user, which takes time. So you can't just assume that the permissions are there straight after you call `requestPermissions()`. Instead you have to wait for when the permissions are granted, and then get the token.

You do this by waiting for the promise returned by `requestPermissions`:

```
FCM = firebase.messaging(); 
DB = firebase.database().ref('deviceTokens/'); 

getPushToken() {
  FCM.requestPermissions().then(() => {
    FCM.getToken().then(token => {
      DB.push(token);
     });
  });
}
```